# Software that test your memory in Mac?

Tags: mac, macbook, memory

I just bought some more Ram but the computer hangs up on and off.

Are there any software that test RAM and see if they are corrupted or intact?

I've got a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 5):

There's [Memtest for OSX](http://www.memtestosx.org/)

Not updated since October 2008 though.

There's also a [Testing RAM](http://guides.macrumors.com/Testing_RAM) page on Mac Rumors which might be a little bit more up to date.

For Intel based Macs there's [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) (thanks to [Josh](https://superuser.com/users/11945/josh) for the link)

Comment: It looks very old. Why isn't there up-to-date RAM tester? Sounds like an urgent tool.

Comment: @ajsie - I don't know. I would have thought there was something more up-to-date, but nothing else turned up from a quick search.

Comment: Even though it's old, I have used it with great success. But if it's an intel mac, you should use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

Comment: "Memetest". Love the typo.

Comment: @David - cheers - I'll fix that

Comment: @Daniel: That's a lexical parser used on Meta to determine if a post has enough freehand circles/waffles/unicorns... ChrisF was probably just confused ;-)

Answer (score 3):

ChrisF hit the nail on the head, [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) is by far the best solution. But if you want a quick and easy fix, use the [Apple Hardware Test DVD which came with your mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509). it's not nearly as thorough as Memtest but it will show you serious errors. It also tests other hardware, like the CPU, GPU, Hard Disk and logic board.

If The Apple Hardware Test DVD doesn't show any issues, definitely try Memtest. We had a Power Mac G5 in the office which AHT shoed no issues with (even after being run in looping mode for days on end) but Memtest showed errors with after only a few passes. So keep that in mind, memtest is much more thorough for RAM testing...

Answer (score 0):

My 2 Cents: I recently had one of my 1GB DDR2 RAM Fail, causing multiple kernel panics. I used Memtest for OSX like mentioned above, and then since I had no access to my install Disk (Travelling abroad) I had a friend lend me his [Techtool](http://www.micromat.com/) Bootable DVD and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the machines PRAM needs resetting: reboot it, holding down option-command-P-R until the third startup chime is heard. This was recommended by a support person at OWC